# Escape characters in rename command

Tags: bash, shell, rename

I have a rename command as follows:

```
rename ".csv" "-en.csv" Daily_vills.csv
rename "^" "07302019" Daily*
```

when i run this, i get an error **"rename: invalid option -- 'e'"**. I already tried "\-en.csv", but this results in **"Daily_vills\-en.csv"**

my question is how to make bash understand that -en is a replacement value and not a parameter.

**original:**

```
Daily_vills.csv
```

**Target;**

```
07302019Daily_vills-en.csv
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Does `rename -- ".csv" "-en.csv" Daily_vills.csv` work?

Comment: let me try this format.

Comment: Why are you using `rename` to rename a single file? `mv Daily_vills.csv 07302019Daily_vills-en.csv`.

Comment: this is not for a single file but for a group of files inside a folder

Comment: @KamilCuk This helped. can you explain how this is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--` to notify `rename` of end of options.

```
rename -- ".csv" "-en.csv" Daily_vills.csv
```

From [posix utility conventions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html):

> Guideline 10:
>
> The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the '-' character.

It is common in many *nix tools to notify with `--` the end of options. Examples:

```
# touch a file named -a
touch -- -a
# cat a file named -a
cat -- -a
# printf the string -b
printf -- -b
# find a string '-c' in files in current directory
grep -- -c *
```

The `rename` utility also follows the guideline from posix utility conventions. The `--` may be used to notify `rename` of the end of options.

Comment: it really helps.. Thanks for digging this out.